# prompted for ssh passphrase after ever push/pull

Tags: git, powershell, ssh, terminal, gitlab

I already asked this question in the [DevOps stackexchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/15040/git-keeps-asking-for-ssh-passphrase-when-ssh-is-already-defined-in-gitlab) because I thought it would be more appropriate there, however it has been a couple of days and I got no response, so I resort to asking here.

I'm playing around with a personal GitLab account to get familiar with its' ins and outs. First, I followed [this primer](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/) on setting ssh keys and added public and private ED25519 keys to `~\.ssh`. I added the public key to my GitLab account. Then, using the `glab` CLI I was able to set up a repository which I could push to and pull from using `git`.

Unfortunately, `git` still prompts me for my SSH passphrase every time I try to push to the repo. I tried the following:

- Adding [known hosts entries](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#ssh-known_hosts-entries)
- [Verifying that I could connect](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#verify-that-you-can-connect) using `ssh -T https://gitlab.com/my_username`

The known host entries didn't have any noticeable effect on this behavior. Verifying I could connect threw the following error:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname https://gitlab.com/my_username

Why is `git` asking me to provide my passphrase every time I push and how can I fix this once and for all?

Comment: If you've set a passphrase on your ssh keys, ssh (not Git!) needs the passphrase to *decrypt* the keys so that it can see them. You'll need to provide the passphrase or run an agent that can store and forward the keys. The "could not resolve hostname" error is unrelated: it indicates that your system cannot turn `gitlab.com` into an IP address, so you need to look into how your system does that.

Comment: I have since solved the "could not resolve hostname" issue. I am using an https link, so it makes sense that `ssh` could not resolve it. When I used the link `git@gitlab.com` it worked as expected. Regarding your first point, how can I store and forward the keys on windows such that I don't have to enter the passphrase every time?

Comment: I'm not sure, as I don't use Windows. On Unix systems, `ssh-agent` will do this kind of thing, and there's no doubt a Windows port, but where you get it and how you set it up, I have no idea. But as for the host name resolving: it *should not* matter whether you use https or ssh, as both need to turn a host name into an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

> When I used the link git@gitlab.com it worked as expected. Regarding your first point, how can I store and forward the keys on windows such that I don't have to enter the passphrase every time?

You can use a `%USERPROFILE%\.bashrc` file (even on Windows), just like [GitHub describes](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows) (it applies to GitLab too)

You can then open a Git bash, and check a `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com` works, provided you have added your public key to your GitLab profile.